# CSS changes after running yarn build in react

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

In my local development environment, everything works as I intended. However in after running yarn build all of my styles are way different. I used create-react-app to set up the project, and I am using regular CSS to style it.
here is my file structure [image]

and here is an example of what I am talking about.
[image]

and here
[image]

Comment: maybe you are missing something try to build again!!

Answer (score 1):

turns out there was nothing wrong with my code I was just zoomed in 500% so embarrassing